# javascript as oop possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I have a div tag and the javascript which creates the fadein/fadeout effect on the div tag. I like to use the same javascript on different div tags so im not recreating the javascript all the time.

how do i do this or is this possible with javascript?
example in php oop would be object->getdata();, how this done in javascript?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () 
        {   var $element = $('#ad1');
            function fadeInOut () 
            {   $element.fadeIn(8000, function () 
                {   $element.fadeOut(1000, function () 
                    {   $element.fadeIn(1500, function () 
                        {   setTimeout(fadeInOut, 5000);
                        });
                    });
                });
            }
            fadeInOut();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Just make `'#ad1'` a variable and make this a reusable function...? This has little to do with OOP.

Comment: If you want to do this on multiple elements, consider using classes instead.

Comment: How to inherit from javascript object, i'm stuck here...

Comment: @undefined And even some of those are objects...

Answer (score 8):

You could write a small jQuery plugin (see also [jQuery Plugin boilerplate](http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/jquery-plugin-boilerplate-revisited/)).

If you want your code to be reuseable, all you have to do is to copy paste it into a `jQuery.fn` function:

```
      jQuery.fn.fadeEffect = function(){
        var $element = this;
        function fadeInOut () 
        {   $element.fadeIn(8000, function () 
            {   $element.fadeOut(1000, function () 
                {   $element.fadeIn(1500, function () 
                    {   setTimeout(fadeInOut, 5000);
                    });
                });
            });
        }
        fadeInOut();
     };
```

Now you can call this plugin multiple times:

```
     $('#ad1').fadeEffect();
     $('#ad2').fadeEffect();
```

jQuery animations add up to a queue so you could optimize your code a little bit:

```
$element
  .fadeIn(8000)
  .fadeOut(1000)
  .fadeIn(1500, function(){
     setTimeout(fadeInOut, 5000);
  })
```

Comment: The callback I believe is so all the animations dont trigger all at once because animations are triggered in async.

Comment: @JordanDoyle jQuery animate has a queue argument which is set to true by default: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Well then looks like my comment is invalid. Upvoted

Answer (score 0):

You could simply made a function.

```
        function fadeInOut ($element) 
            {   $element.fadeIn(8000, function () 
                {   $element.fadeOut(1000, function () 
                    {  ........
                    });
                });
            }
```

Then, call it by :

```
       fadeInOut($('#ad1'));
       fadeInOut($('#ad2'));
```